# Hash Sum Mismatch while updating libcairo2

Tags: apt, updates, intel-graphics, cairo

I installed Intel Graphics Update Tool for Ubuntu 16.10, and after setting the appropriate key from the official 01.org website, when I try to install, I come across this error

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libcairo2-dev
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 702 kB/1.588 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12,3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Get:1 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.10/main yakkety/main amd64 libcairo2 amd64 1.15.2-0intel1 [568 kB]
Err:1 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.10/main yakkety/main amd64 libcairo2 amd64 1.15.2-0intel1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:756ffe6dd23ed29c03295f86d8aca62981b85cc2dee42ed47f7fd61949b2fa13
   - SHA1:60c3d1e510af79c9cdc6b2204e61ec5cbb5f2c23 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:84bbaf1c1c20554bc033dccb4170095a [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:568080 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:cc21a8a43200a3d35624e0bd23849ca30c50ef255fb37ed7502cfa8c6ca34381
   - SHA1:640e49e1339734a385cbffca29485d6e866643e7 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:7c853ef25e2ecf23f9774dba49d39a2d [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:568080 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 17:30:20 +0000
Get:2 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.10/main yakkety/main amd64 libcairo-gobject2 amd64 1.15.2-0intel1 [134 kB]
Err:2 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.10/main yakkety/main amd64 libcairo-gobject2 amd64 1.15.2-0intel1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:c6b3b0670e833d16bd42355550dd3ceeb1567a540c1d8756da4af8359cca746d
   - SHA1:26350d583bbebd0d946e243bfa5da3c1b8464271 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:7fb0231133cee558fa8f7dea48b38b14 [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:133758 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:3d50aa89644a9a79ce8d56a22f33ada99b00aa5634ef306fd07c4994ba7a701e
   - SHA1:56f5eba1d34782ab2a36ea96cbc0d67fa3b36baf [weak]
   - MD5Sum:086ef35715963d3c674a5a654d4923bf [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:133758 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 17:30:19 +0000
Fetched 702 kB in 1s (366 kB/s)
```

Can you suggest me a way to fix it? Thanks!

EDIT. I tried `sudo apt clean`, `sudo apt autoclean`. I tried to remove the program and the list files created by apt update. But no luck so far.

EDIT 2. It now works! It seems they fixed it.

Comment: Try `apt-get clean` and re-try.

Comment: @George I already did what you suggested, with no luck

Comment: Another option I saw was to `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` then run `sudo apt update` then retry, but this will mean massive download...

Comment: @George doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue will be fixed soon, but for now you can go to Software & Updates, activate "Other Software" tab and deselect this one https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.10/main

I just tried it, and it works. You can enable it later (day or two) and try to update again.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
```

Generate a new sources.list file, this can be done from [this site](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/). In this site you will be needed to enter your country, Ubuntu Release and check the packages sources, then click the Generate button at the end of the page to generate a sources.list file.

Copy the link that will appear in a format:

```
curl https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt//sources_d423......
```

in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```